# Как получить результат работы $http из фабрики?

Tags: angularjs

Вот код:

```js
(function() {
 angular.module('pictures', []);

 angular.module('pictures')
  .controller("PicturesController", ['picturesFactory', PicturesController]);

  function PicturesController(picturesFactory) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.pictures = picturesFactory.getHttp();
   /*
   vm.pictures = [];
   
           $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos').success(function(data) {
    vm.pictures = data;
   });
   */
  };
 
 angular.module('pictures')
  .factory("picturesFactory", ['$http', picturesFactory]);

  function picturesFactory($http) {
      
   var getHttp = function() {
    var pictures = [];
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos').success(function(data) {
     pictures = data;
    });
    return pictures;
   };
   
   return {getHttp: getHttp};
  };
 
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='pictures'>
<head>
 <title>NG</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 
 <div id='pictures-list' ng-controller='PicturesController as pictures'>
  <ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat='pict in pictures.pictures'>{{pict.thumbnailUrl}}<br>{{pict.title}}</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Если раскомментировать коммент в контроллере, то запрос работает нормально. Из фабрики почему-то ничего не выходит. Не могу понять где косяк.

Comment: Если в двух словах, то об изменениях в фабрике никто не узнает. Да и запросы фабрика слать не должна. Переносите запросы в сервис, тогда и работать будет.

Comment: @shatal, какая разница? Почему фабрика не должна слать запросы? Здесь проблема вообще не в этом.

Comment: @Andrey, в чем проблема я написал в самом начале. А вот почему шкаф не должен ходить в магазин за одеждой сам, подумайте сами.

Comment: все парни ) я разобрался... кстати это действительно НЕ имеет значения откуда слать запросы... все делал почти правильно... но из-за маленького почти возвращался пустой массив...

Answer (score 1):

#### Ошибка

Этот код

```
var pictures = [];
$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos').success(function(data) {
 pictures = data;
});
return pictures;
```

Всегда вернет `[]`, хоть `success` и вызывается.

#### Ремарка на тему "места" вызова

Не имеет никакого значения, то откуда будет вызываться код. Написание влияет на:

- возможность повторного использования элементов в коде и самого кода
- ремонтопригодность
- читаемость

Если это всё приложение, то зачем создавать фабрику и указывать дополнительные ссылки? А если объект `getHttp` будет иметь с десяток свойств как из примера?

#### Пример

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('pictures', ['angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate']);

  angular.module('pictures').controller('PicturesController', [
    'picturesFactory', PicturesController
  ]);

  function PicturesController(picturesFactory) {
    var scope = this;
    picturesFactory.getHttp.success(function(data) {
      scope.pictures = data
    });
  }

  angular.module('pictures').factory('picturesFactory', [
    '$http', picturesFactory
  ]);

  function picturesFactory($http) {
    var getHttp = $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
    return {
      getHttp: getHttp
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='pictures'>

<head>
  <title>NG</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.7.1/loading-bar.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id='pictures-list' ng-controller='PicturesController as pictures'>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat='pict in pictures.pictures' ng-class-even="'list-group-item-info'">{{pict.thumbnailUrl}}
          <br />{{pict.title}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.7.1/loading-bar.min.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```